# Jenkins Failed to send out email

Tags: jenkins

while I am trying to send email through Jenkins I am getting the issue.

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;

Comment: What Mail Transfer Server do you use? Postfix, Sendmail,...?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more a firewall issue :(

Can you try to launch this command on your Jenkins machine?

```
telnet your.smtp.server.com 25
```

If the test is successful, you should receive a message like that:

```
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to your.smtp.server.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 your.smtp.server.com ESMTP Postfix
```

If you don't receive this message, try to open the port 25 on your Jenkins machine.